# Laravel: Search mysql LIKE using php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have query filter which I use to filter and search tables in my app.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

abstract class QueryFilter

{
  protected $request;

  protected $builder;

  public function  __construct(Request $request)
  {
     $this->request = $request;
  }

  public  function apply(Builder $builder)
  {
    $this->builder = $builder;

    foreach ($this->filters() as $name => $value) {
        if (method_exists($this, $name)) {
            call_user_func_array([$this, $name], 
            array_filter([$value]));
        }

     }

       return $this->builder;
   }

   public function filters()
   {
       return $this->request->all();
   }

}
```

Then add filter to model where i want to use it:

```
    public function scopeFilter($query, QueryFilter $filters)
    {
        return $filters->apply($query);
    }
```

Then create a ModelFilter for this model:

```
class ModelFilters extends QueryFilter
{
    // search by one input
    public function name($name)
    {
        return $this->builder->where('name', $name);
    }

    // serch LIKE by one input
    public function name($name)
    {
        return $this->builder->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$name%");
    }

    // this function is not working
    public function name($name)
    {
        return $this->builder->whereIn('name', 'LIKE', "%(array)$name%");
    }
}
```

Now how can I search database LIKE using an array?

Current function returns an error:

> at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Array to string conversion',
>   '/Users/apple/projects/laravel/app/ModelFilters.php', 66, array('name'
>   => array('10', '8'), 'str' => array('10', '8')))

Answer (score 0):

Finally! With help of my friends, we found a solution.

```
    public function name($name)
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) {

            $this->builder->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $chassis[$i] . '%');
        }

        return $this->builder;
    }
```